# How to hide parent div based on child name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with numerous divs. The main div contains 3 sub divs. I put a search box and i want to show the main div based on what i type and hide the others.

I looked on the internet and so far i managed to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/qaho8hjt/6/

```
$('.my-textbox').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');        

    $('.change_req .orizontala').each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($('.projectName', this).text());
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
    });
});
```

The problem is that i don't know how to hide the parent div. I can only hide the div that i search for.

Thank you.

Edit: Thank you all for you're responses.

Comment: would you please post your html code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is almost fine, just that you are hiding the div that has the content where you should be hiding its immediate parent, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/qaho8hjt/9/)

replace

```
$(this).toggle(isMatch);
```

with

```
$(this).parent().toggle(isMatch);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest()` to get the nearest containing `div`. Try this:

```
$(this).closest('.change_req').toggle(isMatch);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qaho8hjt/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$(this).parent().toggle(isMatch);
```

See your edited code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/qaho8hjt/10/).

Comment: Just FYI, `$(this).parent()` already returns a jQuery object, you don't need to put it inside another jQuery object.